# [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function radians(text) does not exist

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using "radians" in my Redshift query but getting error as " Invalid operation: function radians(text) does not exist".

I am calculating some values and then "redians" will be implemented on the result, for example: radians((val2 - val1) / 2)), I do not know why it is considering the result as "text"!!

Answer (score 2):

If you ensure that both of the imput values into the RADIANS function are double, e.g. convert val2::float8 and val1::float8, this should work.